# edittext inside an imageview

Tags: java, android, android-layout

i have a edittext image that i created in photoshop. then i bring it into my app and put a edittext inside it(my imageview is a frame for my edittext). in fact, i put these two inside a relativelayout and my problem is that when i test my app in twho screen sizes, these two (imagebox and edittext) doesnt resize in the same value and always my edittext resizes much more than my imageview. i want these two in every situation stay together.

[image]

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking here.  Can you be more clear?

Answer (score 1):

The best way in my opinion is to convert your image to a [**9-patch**](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html), with the padding information matching the part of your image containing the actual input zone.

You can then set the 9-patch as the background of your `TextView` or `EditText`. You don't need any container to hold the image. You can even use a style for re-use.

The Android system will hande the resizing of the background, so you just don't have to do anything special after that

Answer (score 0):

You want to be using a `FrameLayout` rather than a `RelativeLayout` if you're planning on using images.